# Use SRTP for secure UDP multicast communication

Tags: sockets, security, udp, rtp, dtls

I am thinking about a way to achieve UDP multicast security. I know that this is a general known issue in networking and I couldn't really find a solution to achieve this. 
During research I've found SRTP as an extension to RTP which implements security aspects and is based on UDP. I've also found out that SRTP supports multicast communication. So I am asking myself if it is possible to use SRTP to achieve my goal? 
If yes why is SRTP not generally used to solve this issue? What are disadvantages of using SRTP to realize secure UDP multicast?

Answer (score 0):

SRTP is part of the SIP VoIP model.  With SIP, two people are communicating.  The symmetric keys required by SRTP are exchanged during SIP communication within TLS.  You could, theoretically, communicate the same key material to each Multicast UDP listener through a secure channel. But each listener would need to have the same symmetric key that was used to encrypt the data.